# Speed up Pandas filtering

Tags: python, performance, optimization, numpy, pandas

I have a 37456153 rows x 3 columns Pandas dataframe consisting of the following columns: `[Timestamp, Span, Elevation]`. Each `Timestamp` value has approximately 62000 rows of `Span` and `Elevation` data, which looks like (when filtered for `Timestamp = 17210`, as an example):

```
        Timestamp       Span  Elevation
94614       17210  -0.019766     36.571
94615       17210  -0.019656     36.453
94616       17210  -0.019447     36.506
94617       17210  -0.018810     36.507
94618       17210  -0.017883     36.502

...           ...        ...        ...
157188      17210  91.004000     33.493
157189      17210  91.005000     33.501
157190      17210  91.010000     33.497
157191      17210  91.012000     33.500
157192      17210  91.013000     33.503
```

As seen above, the `Span` data is not equal spaced, which I actually need it to be. So I came up with the following code to convert it into an equal spaced format. I know the `start` and `end` locations I'd like to analyze. Then I defined a `delta` parameter as my increment. I created a numpy array called `mesh`, which holds the equal spaced `Span` data I would like to end up with. Finally, I decided the iterate over the dataframe for a given `TimeStamp` (17300 in the code) to test how fast it would work. The for loop in the code calculates average `Elevation` values for a +/- `0.5delta` range at each increment.

My problem is: it takes 603 ms to filter through dataframe and calculate the average `Elevation` at a **single** iteration. For the given parameters, I have to go through 9101 iterations, resulting in approximately 1.5 hrs of computing time for this loop to end. Moreover, this is for a single `Timestamp` value, and I have 600 of them (900 hrs to do all?!).

Is there any way that I can speed up this loop? Thanks a lot for any input!

```
# MESH GENERATION
start = 0
end = 91
delta = 0.01

mesh = np.linspace(start,end, num=(end/delta + 1))
elevation_list =[]

#Loop below will take forever to run, any idea about how to optimize it?!

for current_loc in mesh:
    average_elevation = np.average(df[(df.Timestamp == 17300) & 
                                      (df.Span > current_loc - delta/2) & 
                                      (df.Span < current_loc + delta/2)].Span)
     elevation_list.append(average_elevation)
```

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you could use pandas built in moving average/sliding windows functionality, combined with a group by and apply.

Comment: If you have a good reason for not doing that though,  pull your timestamp condition or off the loop into a temporary dataframe

Comment: You could also look into reimplementing your function with cython http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html.

Comment: @sirlak wow... using a temporary df reduces the amount of time for that loop to run down to 1.29 ms. laughing at my stupidty :) creating the temporary df as `df2 = df[df.Timestamp == 17300]` takes 260ms or so, and I had been unnecessarily re-filtering to whole big df all the time in the original loop.

Comment: @Ron I used cython a couple of months ago to speed up a time consuming Monte Carlo analysis, and got good results. Never tried it with pandas though. I will check the documentation, to see if I can get this faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can vectorize the whole thing using `np.searchsorted`. I am not much of a pandas user, but something like this should work, and runs reasonably fast on my system. Using chrisb's dummy data:

```
In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: mesh = np.linspace(start, end, num=(end/delta + 1))
   ...: midpoints = (mesh[:-1] + mesh[1:]) / 2
   ...: idx = np.searchsorted(midpoints, df.Span)
   ...: averages = np.bincount(idx, weights=df.Elevation, minlength=len(mesh))
   ...: averages /= np.bincount(idx, minlength=len(mesh))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop
```

That is about 3500x faster than your code:

```
In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: mesh = np.linspace(start, end, num=(end/delta + 1))
    ...: elevation_list =[]
    ...: for current_loc in mesh:
    ...:     average_elevation = np.average(df[(df.Span > current_loc - delta/2) & 
    ...:                                       (df.Span < current_loc + delta/2)].Span)
    ...:     elevation_list.append(average_elevation)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 19.1 s per loop
```

---

**EDIT** So how does this works? In `midpoints` we store a sorted list of the boundaries between buckets. We then do a binary search with `searchsorted` on this sorted list, and get `idx`, which basically tells us into which bucket each data point belongs. All that is left is to group all the values in each bucket. That's what `bincount` is for. Given an array of ints, it counts how many times each number comes up. Given an array of ints , and a corresponding array of `weights`, instead of adding 1 to the tally for the bucket, it adds the corresponding value in `weights`. With two calls to `bincount` you get the sum and the number of items per bucket: divide them and you get the bucket average.

Comment: Great answer, I had never heard of `np.searchsorted` it's definitely the way to go here.

Comment: @Jaime this works like a charm. I am trying to figure out what's going on after the `idx` calculation though (I checked the `np.bincount` documentation, but got confused a bit). Could you elaborate on the logic? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea - may still be too slow but I thought I'd share.  First, some dummy data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Timestamp': 17210, 
                        'Span': np.linspace(-1, 92, num=60000), 
                        'Elevation': np.linspace(33., 37., num=60000)})
```

Then, take mesh array you created, turn it into a dataframe, and add a shifted entry, so each entry in the dataframe represents one step of the new even Span.

```
mesh_df = pd.DataFrame(mesh, columns=['Equal_Span'])
mesh_df['Equal_Span_Prev'] = mesh_df['Equal_Span'].shift(1)
mesh_df = mesh_df.dropna()
```

Next, I want to join this dataframe with the the larger dataset, based on the entry being between the two `Equal_Span` columns.  There may be a way in pandas, but cartesian-type joins seem much easier to express in SQL, so first, I'm shipping all the data to an in-memory sqlite database. If you run into memory problems I'd make this a file based db.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df.to_sql('df', con, index=False)
mesh_df.to_sql('mesh_df', con, index=False)
```

Here's the main query.  Took about 1m30s on my test data, so this will likely still take a long time on the full dataset.

```
join_df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT a.Timestamp, a.Span, a.Elevation, b.Equal_Span
                         FROM df a, mesh_df b
                         WHERE a.Span BETWEEN b.Equal_Span_Prev AND b.Equal_Span""", con)
```

But once the data is in this form, it's easy/fast to get the desired mean.

```
join_df.groupby(['Timestamp','Equal_Span'])['Elevation'].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, it does not improve the computation time much in this problem, but I will keep in mind `sqlite3` is an option when dealing with other projects.